# Intuitive descriptions of some large cardinals

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, large-cardinals

I was trying to formulate intuitive descriptions of some large cardinals.
Roughly something equivalent to "A manifold is an object which looks like patches of $R^n$ glued together". Not perfectly rigorous, but hopefully conveys the basic picture.
Here are three descriptions I have in mind:
1) An inaccessible cardinal is a set so large that it can't be reached from smaller infinite sets using unions and power set operations.
2) A measurable cardinal is a set so large that it can't be reached from smaller infinite sets using any set theoretic formula. (I am going for V $\neq$ L)
3) A Reinhardt cardinal is a set so large that all possible properties of the entire set theoretic universe are also true of this set. (If I am correct, this would capture the intuition of why Reinhardt cardinals don't exist. They are simply too ambitious).
I am pretty confident that description 1 is correct in essentials, but are 2) and 3) hopelessly off ? If so, how would one appropriately modify the descriptions ? Or are object like measurable cardinals just too abstract to be expressed in anything but technical definitions ?
Apologies in advance if this question is too elementary for MathOverflow.

Comment: Round about here https://books.google.com/books?id=K_11oQjZgrAC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=rudy+rucker+large+cardinals&source=bl&ots=CGlvnlgoxG&sig=Kr-zZg7rJ7Eow6-B2aHw5ldVgIo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH_JTHncTNAhWMGB4KHZuJBfcQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=rudy%20rucker%20large%20cardinals&f=false Rudy Rucker in his Infinity and the Mind attempts to give intuitive descriptions of large cardinals.

Comment: Todd, Rudy Rucker's book was what got me wondering about this question. He stops short of explaining measurable cardinals, except for saying "they are so big that comparing them to run-of-the-mill inaccessibles is like comparing $\omega$ to 2". But the definition of a measurable cardinal does little to convey WHY it is so large.

Comment: Large cardinals are not intuitive.

Comment: Another candidate, although a bit more difficult is "an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ is Mahlo if for any $f:\kappa\to\kappa$, there is an inaccessible cardinal $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $\lambda$ is closed under $f$". You can show there are, e.g., many inaccessibles below $\kappa$ by letting $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ enumerate the inaccessible cardinals below $\kappa$, then there must be a point closed under the enumeration of inaccessibles below $\kappa$. We can get stronger results for different choice of $f:\kappa\to\kappa$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(1) seems okay, but I'm afraid that most large cardinal properties beyond inaccessibility probably aren't going to admit such simple formulations.

I'm not sure I understand the precise meaning of (2), but in any case it doesn't seem right.  For one thing, the existence of $0^\sharp$ is weaker than the existence of a measurable cardinal and still implies $V \ne L$. Also if $0^\sharp$ exists then there are many cardinals, namely indiscernibles for $L$, that seem to satisfy (2) but are not measurable.

I don't think (3) is right either.  To me it sounds like it describes a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa$ is an elementary substructure of $V$.  The existence of such a cardinal is much weaker than the existence of a Reinhardt cardinal, and in fact is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by a compactness argument.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. I was just wondering if there is any intuitive way to convey WHY one expects a Reinhardt cardinal to be humongously large - to the point of inconsistency with ZFC.

Comment: Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent with ZFC by [Kunen's inconsistency theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunen%27s_inconsistency_theorem) and Hugh Woodin has [conjectured](http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Woodin_TheTransfiniteUniverse.pdf) them to be inconsistent with ZF as well.  I don't know any intuitive explanation of either of these things.

Comment: Why Reinhardt cardinals would be considered very large is a simpler matter.  Consider that (to use some common examples of large cardinals) every measurable cardinal is a limit of inaccessible cardinals, every Woodin cardinal is a limit of measurable cardinals, every superstrong cardinal is a limit of Woodin cardinals, etc., and Reinhardt cardinals occur very far up in this "hierarchy" of large cardinals.